# windows.h - Beep()

Tags: c++, windows

Does the Beep() function actually freeze the console for the duration the beep happens. When we use the Sleep() function for Sleep(1000) , we stop execution for 1 second. I'm wondering if the beep also does that

Example

Beep(1000,500) - Freezes console for one second ?

Thanks

Comment: You could compile and run a sample program that uses the function and see whether `Beep` does that for yourself.

Comment: "Beep(1000,500) - Freezes console for one second ?" 500-> 500 ms-> 1/2 second. Is this wait bad for you or good?

Comment: Yes im running g 20 frames a second, that's 20 x 50 milliseconds. So a beep really murders that idea. But its not crucial project. Just college assignment and im well over the mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679277(v=vs.85).aspx)

> Generates simple tones on the speaker. The function is synchronous; it performs an **alertable wait** and **does not return control to its caller until the sound finishes.**

An alertable wait can be interrupted by sending a message to the the thread's message queue. This usually requires an IO completion or some deliberate action, but it can return early and can't be counted on for timing.

To vary the length of the beep, set parameter `dwDuration` accordingly.

If your concern is a non-responsive console, use another thread to send the beep. [`std::async` may be helpful here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async). Eg:

```
auto asyncbeep = std::async(std::launch::async, []{ Beep(1000,500); });
```

Comment: I went to your link and ran the piece of code they provide there in Visual Studio
Gave Error - Any ideas
#error <future> is not supported when compiling with /clr or /clr:pure.

Comment: It sounds like you've made a managed C++ project.  You should choose "Win32 Console Application" when you create your project instead.

Comment: Mmmm... How do I check that. 
Project->Properties-> says ->target platform windows

Comment: I think I made a CLR Empty C++ project !

Comment: @Daniel darn good question. I don't have a copy of Visual Studio on hand to suggest how to get around that other than create a win32 project and copy your code over. Alternative is stay in the lands of CLR and use [System::Thread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread(v=vs.110).aspx), about which I know too little to make good suggestions.

Comment: OK im gonna try see can i get some System::Thread examples working .. Thanks for time. well received

Comment: @Daniel Not a problem. If you run into trouble with that, I recommend tagging the questions with `c++-clr`. You'll get a better-targeted pool of people reading the question.

Answer (score 0):

[This website](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679277(v=vs.85).aspx) has the answer.

> The function is synchronous; it performs an alertable wait and does not return control to its caller until the sound finishes.

So it does pause, just like `Sleep()`.